# Changing the current configuration used by (Web)ConfigurationManager

Tags: asp.net, configurationmanager

I'm using `WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration` to load a custom configuration file and get it merged with the main `web.config`. I can use the resulting `Configuration` to configure my own framework and benefit from having a clean custom configuration file and a standard `web.config` and use the merged view at runtime.

The problem is that now I want to tell ASP.NET to use that `Configuration` instance as the default, so that `WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("mySection")` will return the section defined in my loaded configuration file.

Is there any way of doing this with "standard" practices? (anything involving `X(ml)Document` or reflection to get private methods is not acceptable)

Answer (score 0):

Will [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151435.aspx) overload of the GetSection() methos satisfy your needs? It allows you specify a path to the web.config file from which to load data and would look like this:

```
WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("connectionStrings", "/configTest")
```

Comment: Not really. I need to replace the default one so the rest of the ASP.NET stack use it by default

Comment: In this case, since the WebConfigurationManager.GetSection() _Retrieves the specified configuration section from the current Web application's default configuration file._, you need to promote the merge result to the default configuration file: _config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);_

Comment: I guess you either misunderstood the question or the MSDN docs. I don't want to save the configuration to a file (you don't want /can't do that on a web app). I just want to make it the current configuration.